# Version code being displayed instead of Version Name in Samsung Galaxy S - GT I9000 device?

Tags: android, versioning

I do not know what is the reason of this but I just installed one Android app in Samsung Galaxy S - GT I9000 device and its displaying Version code in App info screen. Whereas the Nexus One is displaying the proper Version Name and not Version code.

Has anyone faced a similar issue and is there any solution to this?

Comment: Noticing the same problem here. It happens in 1.6 and 2.1 but is fixed in 2.2 onward. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also facing this same problem on a HTC Tattoo 1.6 and on a LG GT540. In the application manager the version shown is the versionCode instead of the versionName. This is due to faulty implementations. And the only solution I can see is they release new firmwares with that bug fixed. BTW, it would nice to have a list on the devices with that bug.
Regards

PS: I wonder why my previous post was deleted by Mr. Mod :-?

Comment: As said this seems to be firmware issue.